# Key-Value Observing To-Many Relationships in Swift

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, swift, key-value-observing, key-value-coding

When you wanted notification of changes to an `NSMutableArray` in Objective-C, Apple's documentation encouraged you to implement the optional mutable accessors:

> You are strongly advised to implement these mutable accessors rather than relying on an accessor that returns a mutable set [sic] directly. The mutable accessors are much more efficient when making changes to the data in the relationship.

At a bare minimum, for the set-up to work, you needed something like the following. (This was made pretty straight-forward because Xcode's code-completion tool would guess what you were up to and provide you with the signatures.)

```
// Assumes the class to which these methods belong has an NSMutableArray
// property called <children>.

-(void)insertObject:(NSNumber *)object inChildrenAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    [self.children insertObject:object atIndex:index];
}

-(void)removeObjectFromChildrenAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    [self.children removeObjectAtIndex:index];
}
```

I've recently tried to do something similar in Swift (using an `NSMutableArray` **not** a mutable Swift array) but *Xcode* provides no signature hint and the signatures that I try do nothing (see below).

---

Am I simply getting the signatures wrong, or have Apple done away with the need to implement these accessors in Swift? Or perhaps there's a new pattern that I'm not aware of?

---

```
// These accessors don't trigger KVO notifications.

func insertObject(object: AnyObject!, inChildrenAtIndex index: Int) {
    children.insertObject(object, atIndex: index)
}

func removeObjectFromChildrenAtIndex(index: Int) {
    children.removeObjectAtIndex(index)
}

func replaceObjectInChildrenAtIndex(index: Int, withObject object: AnyObject!) {
    children.replaceObjectAtIndex(index, withObject: object)
}
```

Comment: You said you tried with an `NSMutableArray` and did not try with a `var children: [AnyObject]`.  Perhaps you should try with the latter?

Comment: Editing a Swift array actually results in a new array being created, so when the KVO notification comes through the ``kind`` is only ever ``.Setting``. I want something a bit more detailed (like whether the operation was a ``.Insertion`` or ``.Removal``). What's more, there are times when a mutable Swift array cannot be used as a direct replacement for an ``NSMutableArray``, so I want to stick with the ``NSMutableArray`` in this instance. Thanks for the suggestion though.